# What is the best way for a Seller to change a shipping provider for product delivery?

Tags: e-commerce, checkout, b2b, shipping

I am currently designing a checkout flow in Figma for our e-commerce website. We are a B2B marketplace where galleries can post their artworks for sale. Our website partnered with a shipping company. This shipping company charges too much sometimes and we would like to give sellers the power to select an alternative whether they deliver it themselves or choose a different shipping company. My problem is that the selection of shipping method was made when the artwork was created and published. I'm struggling with creating an interface where sellers can change the shipping method in the middle of the checkout process.

[image: Order Page with Shipping Quote]
[image: Order Page to change the Shipping Quote]

Comment: I think you will need to provide at least some visual context for people to really be able to help you.

Comment: Please provide visuals, and describe any constraints as well as your specific efforts so far.

Comment: Hi guys, I just edited and added pictures to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designing a user interface that allows sellers to change the shipping method during the checkout process can be challenging, but it is possible to create a smooth experience. Here are some suggestions to help you design the interface:

- **Add a shipping method step in the checkout flow:**
  Introduce a new step dedicated to confirming/modifying the shipping method in the checkout flow. Provide a summary of the new shipping method, cost, and estimated delivery time. This step gives the seller a chance to review their choice before proceeding to the next step.
- **Communicate the changes:**
  Notify both the buyer and the seller about the updated shipping method via email or any other preferred communication channel. This ensures transparency and keeps both parties informed about the shipping changes.

In summary, the key to creating a smooth interface for changing shipping methods during the checkout process is to introduce a dedicated step for shipping method selection, provide clear alternative options, and ensure transparency in communication.

Comment: Thanks @SylvainBTL, your first suggestion is the lacking feature in our system. We let sellers choose the shipping method upon artwork creation. We can only give limited options for the shipping methods during the checkout flow since I'm not sure if we can still afford to change the entire system. I guess we will capitalize on your second suggestion to make the users understand.